# Windows 10 network can't communicate with other computers

Tags: windows, networking

Two desktops, one laptop, all running the latest Win 10, all on the same workgroup.  File/printer sharing enabled.

About three weeks ago, they stopped talking to one another.  I can see the computer names in my network list.  I can open a cmd box and ping another computer successfully.  But if I try to map a drive or open one of the other computers, it says WINDOWS CANNOT ACCESS \FRONTDESK.

Running network diagnostics is useless.  It basically comes up and says yeah, you can't connect, buh-bye.

I'm at my wit's end.  I have been researching this for weeks.  I've tried everything that I see suggested and I still can't use my network.

Has anyone had this problem and if so, what did you do to fix it?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to reset your network driver to an earlier version?I rather assume that you lack the permissions to access the data.I recommend to re-execute the data release on the target computer.